# ChoosingItemContainerEvent or ItemTemplateSelector

Tags: listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have 3 data templates for a listview. What should I use to assign a template to incoming item - ItemTemplateSelector or the ChoosingItemContainer event attached to the listview?

I was using ItemTemplateSelector until now, but it gives an exception when I scroll the list quickly, probably because of virtualization. The auto-generated tries to typecast the item added first to the data type of presently added item. Can you explain this behavior?

Here is a dummy version of problem I am facing

```
public class Person
{
    public PersonType Type;

    public string Name;
}

public enum PersonType
{
    Employee, Student, Manager
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public string Id;
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public string CollegeName;
}

public class Manager : Person
{
    public string Level;
}
```

In the MainPage.xaml, I have following DataTemplates and ItemTemplateSelector

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="EmployeeTemplate" x:DataType="local:Employee">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Bisque">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" Margin="10,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Id}" Margin="10,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="StudentTemplate" x:DataType="local:Student">
        <RelativePanel Background="Aqua">
            <TextBlock x:Name="NameBlock" Text="{x:Bind Name}" Margin="10,0"/>
            <TextBlock RelativePanel.RightOf="NameBlock" Text="{x:Bind CollegeName}" Margin="10,0"/>
        </RelativePanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ManagerTemplate" x:DataType="local:Manager">
        <Grid Background="BurlyWood">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" Margin="10,0"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind Level}" Margin="10,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:ListViewItemTemplateSelector x:Key="ItemTemplateSelector"
                                        EmployeeTemplate="{StaticResource EmployeeTemplate}"
                                        StudentTemplate="{StaticResource StudentTemplate}"
                                        ManagerTemplate="{StaticResource ManagerTemplate}"/>
```

And I get an exception in MainPage.g.cs when I scroll through the list swiftly

```
public void DataContextChangedHandler(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement sender, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DataContextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
             global::TestApp.Employee data = args.NewValue as global::TestApp.Employee;
             if (args.NewValue != null && data == null)
             {
                throw new global::System.ArgumentException("Incorrect type passed into template. Based on the x:DataType global::TestApp.Employee was expected.");
             }
             this.SetDataRoot(data);
             this.Update();
        }
```

Here, args.newValue contains a Student Item which lies somewhere in the middle of list.

Comment: I don't think virtualisation interfers with item selector.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't. But why is the new item being filled in the container occupied by an old item with different data type?

Comment: Exactly the same problem here: very simple items and their DataTemplates, and a DataTemplateSelector to choose them. I also use compiled bindings. Also suspecting virtualization is somehow leading to the crash. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This exception is not fatal - Visual Studio catches all "enabled" exceptions.

If you want to avoid it being thrown, set ListItemView's content to null when it differs from what the virtualization mechanism has designated for the cell:

```
protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(
    object itemViewModel,
    DependencyObject container)
{    
    var itemView = container as ListViewItem;
    if (itemView != null) {
        var content = itemView.Content;
        if (content != null && content.GetType() != itemViewModel.GetType()) {
            itemView.Content = null;
        }
    }
    ... // return DataTemplate for itemViewModel
}
```